# Помогите пожалуйста, не работает кодировка при выводе таблицы

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Русский не выводится, все файлы сохранены в формате utf-8? вот сам скрипт:

`connect.php`

```
<?php
$hostname='host';
$username='user';
$password='password';
$database='database';

$con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database) or die(mysqli_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
?>
```

`index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>A fancy add,edit,delete ajax paginated mysql table</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://triass.ru/view/style.css" />
<script src="http://triass.ru/view/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pagination.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://triass.ru/view/css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://triass.ru/view/css/component.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://triass.ru/view/css/content.css" />
<script src="http://triass.ru/view/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="formDiv">
          <form id="formSearch" >
            Search by Name <input type="text" id="fieldSearch" name="search_text" >
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
          </form>
       <div  id="divLoading"></div> 
       <div id="selectDiv">
         <small>
          <select id="pageRecord">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option selected value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select><i> Record per Page</i>
         </small>
      </div>
     </div>

    <div  id="divPageData"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`pagination_class.php`

```
<?php


/*
Developed by Reneesh T.K
reneeshtk@gmail.com
You can use it with out any worries...It is free for you..It will display the out put like:
First | Previous | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7| 8 | 9 | 10 | Next | Last
Page : 7  Of  10 . Total Records Found: 20
*/
class Pagination_class{
    var $result;
    var $anchors;
    var $total;
    function Pagination_class($qry,$starting,$recpage)
    {    
        include('connect.php');
        $rst        =   mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die(mysqli_error());
        $numrows    =   mysqli_num_rows($rst);
        $qry         .= " limit $starting, $recpage";
        $this->result   =   mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die(mysqli_error());
        $next       =   $starting+$recpage;
        $var        =   ((intval($numrows/$recpage))-1)*$recpage;
        $page_showing   =   intval($starting/$recpage)+1;
        $total_page =   ceil($numrows/$recpage);

        if($numrows % $recpage != 0){
            $last = ((intval($numrows/$recpage)))*$recpage;
        }else{
            $last = ((intval($numrows/$recpage))-1)*$recpage;
        }
        $previous = $starting-$recpage;
        $anc = "<ul id='pagination-flickr'>";
        if($previous < 0){
            $anc .= "<li class='previous-off'>First</li>";
            $anc .= "<li class='previous-off'>Previous</li>";
        }else{
            $anc .= "<li class='next'><a href='javascript:pagination(0);'>First </a></li>";
            $anc .= "<li class='next'><a href='javascript:pagination($previous);'>Previous </a></li>";
        }

        ################If you dont want the numbers just comment this block############### 
        $norepeat = 4;//no of pages showing in the left and right side of the current page in the anchors 
        $j = 1;
        $anch = "";
        for($i=$page_showing; $i>1; $i--){
            $fpreviousPage = $i-1;
            $page = ceil($fpreviousPage*$recpage)-$recpage;
            $anch = "<li><a href='javascript:pagination($page);'>$fpreviousPage </a></li>".$anch;
            if($j == $norepeat) break;
            $j++;
        }
        $anc .= $anch;
        $anc .= "<li class='active'>".$page_showing."</li>";
        $j = 1;
        for($i=$page_showing; $i<$total_page; $i++){
            $fnextPage = $i+1;
            $page = ceil($fnextPage*$recpage)-$recpage;
            $anc .= "<li><a href='javascript:pagination($page);'>$fnextPage</a></li>";
            if($j==$norepeat) break;
            $j++;
        }
        ############################################################
        if($next >= $numrows){
            $anc .= "<li class='previous-off'>Next</li>";
            $anc .= "<li class='previous-off'>Last</li>";
        }else{
            $anc .= "<li class='next'><a href='javascript:pagination($next);'>Next </a></li>";
            $anc .= "<li class='next'><a href='javascript:pagination($last);'>Last</a></li>";
        }
            $anc .= "</ul>";
        $this->anchors = $anc;

        $this->total = "Page : $page_showing <i> Of   </i> $total_page . Total Records Found: $numrows";
    }
}
?>
```

`process_data.php`

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="add") //menangani aksi penambahan data pelanggan
  {  

     $name=$_POST['add_name'];
     $address=$_POST['add_address'];
     $exam_no=$_POST['add_exam_no'];   $pattern="/^[A-Z]{2}\d{4}\b/";
     if(($name=="")||($address == "")||($exam_no == "")){
      echo '{"status":"1"}';
      exit;
     }
     else if( !preg_match($pattern,$exam_no)){
     echo  '{"status":"2"}';
     exit;
     }else{

     $test=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO students(name,address,exam_no) VALUES('$name','$address','$exam_no')") or die ("data gagal ditambahakan!");

 echo '{"status":"3"}';
     exit;
     }
  }

elseif(isset($_POST['action'])&& $_POST['action']=="update") //menangani aksi perubahan data pelanggan
  {


     $id=$_POST['edit_id'];
     $name=$_POST['edit_name'];
     $address=$_POST['edit_address'];
     $exam_no=$_POST['edit_exam_no'];

     $test = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE students SET name='$name',address='$address',exam_no='$exam_no' WHERE id='$id'") or die ("data gagal di-update!");
     echo '{"status":"3"}';
     exit;
  }
  elseif(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="delete") //menangani aksi penghapusan data pelanggan
  {

     $id = $_POST['delete_id'];
     $test = mysqli_query($con,"delete from students where id='$id'");
     if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1){ //jika jumlah baris data yang dikenai operasi delete == 1
       echo '{"status":"1"}';
     }else{
       echo '{"status":"0"}';
     }
     exit;
  }
  ?>
```

`tablepage.php`

```
<script>
function pagination(page){
 var search = $("input#fieldSearch").val();
 var record = $("select#pageRecord").val(); 
   if (search!==""){
    dataString = 'starting='+page+'&name='+search+'&perpage='+ record+'&random='+Math.random();
  }

  else{
    dataString = 'starting='+page+'&perpage='+record+'&random='+Math.random();
  }

  $.ajax({
    url:"tablepage.php",
    data: dataString,
    type:"GET",
    success:function(data)
    {
      $('#divPageData').html(data);
    }
  });
}

function loadData(){
    var dataString;
    var search = $("input#fieldSearch").val();
    var record = $("select#pageRecord").val();
    dataString = 'name='+ search + '&perpage=' + record;

      $.ajax({
      url: "tablepage.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: dataString,
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#divPageData').html(data);
      }
    });
  }



$('#students tr:even:not(#nav):not(#total)').addClass('even');
$('#students tr:odd:not(#nav):not(#total)').addClass('odd') 
 $("form#form1").submit(function(){
    var vId = $("input#edit_id").val();                  
    var vName = $("input#edit_name").val();                
    var vAddress = $("input#edit_address").val();         
    var vExam = $("input#edit_exam_no").val();             
    var myRegExp=/^[A-Z]{2}\d{4}\b/;                  


    if ((vName=="")||(vAddress == "")||(vExam == "")){
       alert("Please complete the missing field(s)");
        $("input#edit_name").focus();
        return false;
        }
     else if( !myRegExp.test(vExam)){
        alert ('Invalid Format for Exam No.');
        $("input#edit_exam_no").focus();
        return false;
      }
    else{
          $.ajax({
          url: "process_data.php",
          type:$(this).attr("method"), 
          data:$(this).serialize(), 
          dataType: 'json', 
          success:function(response){
             if(response.status == 3) // return nilai dari hasil proses
             {
                  alert("Data Successfully Updated");

                   $(".morph-content").hide(2000);                

                  loadData();
             }
             else if(response.status==1)
             {
                alert("Please complete the missing field(s)");
                $("input#add_name").focus();
             }
             else if(response.status==2)
             {
                alert("Invalid Format for Exam No.");
                $("input#add_exam_no").focus();
             }

             else
             {
                alert("Data update unsccessful");
             }
          }
        });
        return false;
      }
     return false;
  });


  $("form#form2").submit(function(){

          $.ajax({
          url: "process_data.php",
          type:$(this).attr("method"), 
          data:$(this).serialize(), 
          dataType: 'json', 
          success:function(response){
             if(response.status == 1) // return nilai dari hasil proses
             {
                  alert("Data Successfully Delected");

                   $(".morph-content").hide(2000);                

                  loadData();
             }
             else
             {
                alert("Data Failed to Delete");
             }
          }
        });
        return false;


  });  
</script>
<script src="http://triass.ru/view/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="http://triass.ru/view/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="http://triass.ru/view/js/uiMorphingButton_fixed.js"></script>
<script src="http://triass.ru/view/js/buttonMorp.js"></script>


<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
include('pagination_class.php');
include('connect.php');

if (isset($_GET['name']) and !empty($_GET['name'])){
  $name = $_GET['name'];
  $sql = "select * from students where name like '%$name%'";
}
else{
  $sql = "select * from students order by id";
}

if(isset($_GET['starting'])){ //starting page
    $starting=$_GET['starting'];
}else{
    $starting=0;
}

$recpage=$_GET['perpage'];

$obj = new pagination_class($sql,$starting,$recpage);       
$result = $obj->result;
?>       
<div id="page_contents">

  <div id="addDiv">
    <div  class="morph-button morph-button-modal morph-button-modal-2 morph-button-fixed">
        <button type="button">ADD</button>
            <div class="morph-content">
                <div>
                    <div class="content-style-form content-style-form-1">
                      <span class="icon icon-close">Close the dialog</span>
                       <h2>Add Data</h2>
                        <form id="form1" method="post" >
                            <p><label>Name</label><input type="text" id="add_name" name="add_name" /></p>
                            <p><label>Address</label><input type="text" id="add_address" name="add_address" /> </p>
                            <p><label>Exam No. (format: AA000)</label><input type="text" id="add_exam_no" name="add_exam_no" /></p>
                            <p><input type="submit" value="Add" /></p>
                            <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="add" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div id="student_wrap">   
        <table  id="students"  width="100%" >
            <tr><th>Sl No</th><th>Student Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Exam No.</th><th style="padding-left:19px;">Action</th>
            </tr>
                <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0){
                    $counter = $starting + 1;
                    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><?php echo $data['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['address']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['exam_no']; ?></td>
                <td>   
                      <div class="morph-button morph-button-modal morph-button-modal-2 morph-button-fixed">
                        <button type="button">Edit</button>
                        <div class="morph-content">
                            <div>
                                <div class="content-style-form content-style-form-1">
                                    <span class="icon icon-close">Close the dialog</span>
                                    <h2>Update Data</h2>
                                    <form id="form1" method="post" >
                                        <p><label>ID</label><input type="text" id="edit_id" name="edit_id" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" readonly /></p>
                                        <p><label>Name</label><input type="text" id="edit_name" name="edit_name" value="<?php echo $data['name']; ?>" /></p>
                                        <p><label>Address</label><input type="text" id="edit_address" name="edit_address" value="<?php echo $data['address']; ?>" /></p>
                                        <p><label>Exam No. (format: AA000)</label><input type="text" id="edit_exam_no" name="edit_exam_no" value="<?php echo $data['exam_no']; ?>" /></p>
                                        <p><input  type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="morph-button morph-button-modal morph-button-modal-2 morph-button-fixed">
                        <button type="button">Delete</button>
                        <div class="morph-content">
                            <div>
                                <div class="content-style-form content-style-form-1">
                                    <span class="icon icon-close">Close the dialog</span>
                                    <h2>Delete Data</h2>
                                       <p ><h2 style="margin:10px 10px;">Do you really want to delete from "demo" where SL No="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" </h2></p>
                                       <form id="form2" method="post" >
                                        <p><input type="hidden"  name="delete_id" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" /></p>
                                       <p><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></p>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </td> 


            </tr></tbody> <?php } ?>

            <tfoot><tr id="nav"><td colspan="5"><div><?php echo $obj->anchors; ?></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="total"><td colspan="5"><?php echo $obj->total; ?></td>
            </tr>
                <?php } else{ ?>
            <tr><td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
            </tr></tfoot>
                <?php } ?>

        </table>
      </div>        
    </div>
```

`table.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `exam_no` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;
```

Пример можно увидеть на [Ссылка](http://triass.ru/view/)

Comment: как вариант в первом же php-файле `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` и кодировку писал так `mysql_set_charset('utf8');`

Comment: Спасибо , но ничего не произошло ( так же само те же вопросики ..

Comment: данные могли попасть в таблицу в неверной кодировке, добавть вновь строку и проверьте. Также проверьте кодировку самих таблиц в phpmyadmin

Comment: я и не убирал эту строку , кодировка таблиц в phpmyadmin `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Константин, не стоит публиковать такие сведения в открытом виде. Очень рекомендую вам сменить все пароли прямо сейчас.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в таких случаях не только оповещать надо, но и стирать такую информацию.

Comment: @VenZell насколько я помню, мы с Nofate стирали. Странно. На всякий случай стёр ещё раз.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в ajax запрос добавить кодировку -  scriptCharset: "utf-8"

```
$.ajax({
  url: "tablepage.php",
  type: "GET",
  data: dataString,
  scriptCharset: "utf-8",
  success: .....
```

Comment: Извините я без понятия куда это добавлять)) с аджаксом не дружу совсем, тут с php пытаюсь дружится, но что то вроде понял , а все новые и новые траблы